# IPython plugin not loading in QGIS 2.12

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, ubuntu

I am trying to run the IPython console plugin in QGIS 2.12

After installing the plugin there is this error:

> You need to install IPython 3.1.0 (and then restart QGIS) before
>   running this IPyConsole plugin. IPython can be installed with pip
>   install "ipython[all]==3.1.0". More informations about IPython
>   installation on https://ipython.org/install.html

I ran sudo pip install "ipython[all]==3.1.0" ... the installation was successful, but then when I restarted QGIS and tried to open the Ipython console, I got exactly the same error message.
I am running on Ubuntu 14. Python3 is installed separately on my system. Could that be the issue?

Why is QGIS not be able to recognize that I have the correct version of ipython installed?

Answer (score 2):

Try this from the QGIS standard Python console:

```
import IPython; IPython.__version__
```

Comment: I was having the same problem as the OP (successfully installed iPython 3.1.0 via pip, but wasn't recognized by QGIS), and I ran this in the Python console as you suggested and it says 2.4.1 ... But when I run ipython from bash shell, it runs 3.1.0 ... How do I get qgis to recognize the later version of ipython?